# Stripe - Using the PaymentElement to update a Subscription's PaymentMethod mid-cycle

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to allow users to update their subscription's payment method mid cycle. I'm already using the `PaymentElement` when they initially start their subscription, and I'm using it when a user is subscription is `past_due` to change payment methods and charge. I would like to keep things consistent and use it in this mid-cycle situation too.

The problem is, mid-cycle the subscription object does not appear to have any pending `PaymentIntent` or `SetupIntents`, as the next invoice hasn't been created yet, which means I can't pass a `client_secret` to initialize the `PaymentElement`.

Is there a way to do this I'm not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: Great self-solve! I was going to suggest the same thing. I'd recommend restoring the question and putting your solution as an answer, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I've since found a method that works well. A setup intent does not need to be created by the stripe.subscriptions.create() endpoint in order to be attached to the subscription, you can instead create a stripe.setupIntents.create() on the backend, pass the clientSecret to the frontend, present the PaymentElement, and once you confirm the card details attach the new payment_method to the subscription. It will replace the existing one.

You can attach this payment method either by:

1. listening to the setup_intent.succeeded webhook, grab the payment_method id, retrieve your users active subscription.id from your own database, and then call stripe.subscriptions.update() and attach the new payment_method.
2. Or, after the PaymentElement redirects the user back to your website, grab the setup_intent_client_secret from the URL Parameters, and fetch the setup_intent on the frontend, and if valid send the new payment method ID to a backend endpoint to attach.

Method 1 is easier code-wise in my opinion, but method 2 can be implemented "synchronously" so to speak. This could be beneficial, since method 2 does not rely on webhooks you can ensure the payment method is attached before you display any information to your user. With method 1 its technically possible that your user navigates to /yourwebsite/payment-method to look at his card details before the webhook has fired. They might then see their old card details which would understandably be worrying. I ended up moving my strategy to #2.